# Google Chrome: jquery.ajax fails within onclick-event ("failed to load resource")

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, onclick

I use Google Chrome 7.0.x and I have the following javascript-function that gets called when a user clicks a button:

```
function myFunction(myId) {
 $("#" + myId).click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "myURL",
  success: function(msg){
   alert (msg);
  }
 });
});
```

alert() gets never called, instead I get "failed to load resource" when I lock at the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using an asp.net http handler?

Comment: what about firefox , what is fireub showing in net panel , i don't think anything wrong with chrome , your url looks like wrong

Comment: do onething , take url and paste that in browser and check what happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `return false` in the end of the `click` handler, didn't you?

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! Although I dont quite understand yet, why the "return false" is necessary and what it actually does...

Comment: You shouldn't return false, you should `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: from jquery api // Whether to trigger global Ajax event handlers for this request. The default is true. Set to false to prevent the global handlers like ajaxStart or ajaxStop from being triggered. This can be used to control various Ajax Events.

Comment: @paskster can you show us the code which is calling myFunction??

Comment: @paskster `return false` prevents the browser from performing the default action for the button, which is to submit the form. That's why the page was reloaded.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `return false;` you should do `function (e) {` and then immediately on the next line `e.preventDefault();` to stop the default action of the click event and do whatever you tell it to do.  This is much better practice because you will not always want to return false as a value.

```
function myFunction(myId) {
     $("#" + myId).click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myURL",
            success: function(msg){
                 alert (msg);
            }
     });
}    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see what the error is:

```
function myFunction(myId) {
 $("#" + myId).click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "myURL",
  success: function(msg){
   alert (msg);
  },
   error: function (error, t, msg) {
    console.log(error);
        console.log(t);
        console.log(msg);
   }
 });
});
```

Maybe your URL is wrong

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I added your code, but the following happens: When the ajax-method is calld I see the laoding-image, and while loading I can look at the console. But after 2 seconds or so (so not enough time to actually see the error) the logs disappear and the browser stops loading! It kinda feels like the browser is reloading the whole page...

Comment: @passer , open net panel in firebug and see the result, check my other comments.

Comment: @passer , your myURL is in double quotes, if it is dynamie it should be without quotes...

Comment: I cant use firebug for debugging either, because the console shows me the error only for 2 seconds, and then flushes the error log. The url works when I just insert it, into my browser...

Comment: @paskster , remove the code for console.log and use net panel to see the real error , it shows what is the real error , we can easliy know if it is a cross domain issue or some permission issue at the backend, it will show the error in red status, remove that console....code for now.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your URL is wrong , please check url through Firebug net panel   , it should fix the problem.

THere won't be any problem with chrome for the above code.